# Factory injection into factory created object

Tags: patterns-and-practices, factory

```
public class Factory 
{
   public INode CreateNode(TypeEnum type)
   {
       switch(type)
       {
           case TypeEnum.Document:
               return new DocumentNode(this);
           case TypeEnum.Item:
               return new ItemNode();
       }
   }
}

public interface INode
{
    void DoAction();
}

public class ItemNode : INode
{
    void DoAction()
    {
        // Nothing to do or simple action without more childs.
    }
}

public class DocumentNode : INode
{
    private Factory factory;

    public Node(Factory factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void DoAction()
    {
        var nodeTypes = this.GetNodeTypes();
        foreach (var value in nodeTypes)
        {  
            var node = this.factory.CreateObject(value);
            node.DoAction(otherValues);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<TypeEnum> GetNodeTypes()
    {
        // Retrieve values here... Could be DocumentNode or ItemNode types.
    }
}
```

Is it a valid approach and makes sense to inject the factory used to create a class instance into the created instance itself to use it (as a tree)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  If an object needs to create another object of its own type (or of a related type if you have a factory that builds a family of types) then the most sensible solution to me seems to inject its factory at creation time.  In fact, I don't really see any alternative to this approach that doesn't lose the benefits of using factories entirely.